# Plutus V2 Tx Building causing NonOutputSupplimentaryDatums error

Tags: plutus, cardano-serialization-lib, plutus-v2, inline-datum

I am stuck with this error, what's a `NonOutputSupplimentaryDatums`?:

```
""transaction submit error ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraBabbage (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (FromAlonzoUtxowFail (NonOutputSupplimentaryDatums (fromList [SafeHash \"13866df5e21887cb0d2c27b8d8ccf03d1cb7f93e929dffa9a91c8a4b83c98c60\"]) (fromList [])))])""
```

For the reference:

- I am spending a **script input** with **inline datum**
- I am using `add_plutus_script_input` on `TransactionBuilder` to add the input
- I am using `txBuilder.calc_script_data_hash(TxBuilderConstants.plutus_vasil_cost_models());` to get the script witnesses and script hash set up

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use cardano-serialization-lib but I can tell you that `NonOutputSupplimentaryDatums` is the ledger error thrown when datum is unneceserilly included in the tx when using inline datum. When inline datum is being used you can't have the same datum also in the tx body's witness set.

Comment: Thanks for the error explanation! The only datum I am attaching is via TxBuilder#add_plutus_script_input which requires a PlutusWitness that is made up of the script, the **datum** and redeemer.

Comment: This actually helped me solving "unspendableDatums" error from Ogmios. I could not find any docs for it, only the mapping from NonOutputSupplimentaryDatums here: https://github.com/CardanoSolutions/ogmios/blob/756b31cfce0a801526745b39e07c69bc0edaae4a/server/src/Ogmios/Data/Json/Alonzo.hs#LL109C18-L109C46

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to resolve the issue. The problem was caused by the way I attached the datum as `PlutusWitness`. So instead of creating directly instantiating a `PlutusWitness` I created one with the help of the newly made available constructor `PlutusWitness.new_with_ref` in **CSL version 11.1.0**:

```
const txIn = TransactionInput.new(TransactionHash.from_bytes(Buffer.from(o.txId, 'hex')), o.idx);
...
// Caused error:
const errorCausingPlutusWitness = PlutusWitness.new(myContract, myDatum, myRedeemer);

// Valid way:
const plutusWitness = PlutusWitness.new_with_ref(PlutusScriptSource.new(myContract), DatumSource.new_ref_input(txIn), myRedeemer);

const amt = Value.new(BigNum.from_str(`${o.value.coins}`));

// The script input to be spent
txBuilder.add_plutus_script_input(plutusWitness, txIn, amt);
```

Comment: This essentially allowed me to spend an `inline-datum` script output.